# Is there a way to get insert face to be larger than the selected face?

Tags: scale

When you have a face selected and you hit <kbd>I</kbd>, it does this extrude/scale thing where you can give it an exact unit and it will scale it exactly that many units in, but it only does it smaller than the original face. If you were to do <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, then it does the same thing but it scales it as a percentage, though it can be larger than the original face. I need to do the insert face but have it larger than the original face by a specific unit; not a percentage. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I cannot get the Inset action to use anything other than a percentage, which is the behaviour I expect from any of Blenders built in actions/tools. Are you sure you are seeing it use Blender Units rather than a percentage where 0 = 0% and 1.0 = 100% and higher values are allowed. Also, if I make the Inset face larger than the original it turns inside out is this really what you want?

Comment: I have a triangle that has sides of 1000mm each. When I hit `I100`, the inset triangle has sides of about about 900mm. That would be using the units instead of percentages. I want to be able to type `I-100` or something to get one with sides of 1100mm. The math is easy to do with numbers like 1000, but if I didn't know what the size was, but I know it needs to grow by 19mm, then trying to figure out what percentage gets much harder.

Answer (score 1):

You can also outset faces using the inset tool properties panel, just tick "outset".

You can specify the thickness of the outset in units.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that panel. I know those are normally on the bottom left of the screen, but when I hit `I`, it doesn't pop up.